# How to prevent </p> from ending line

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
<p>Dostępne: </p><p style={{color:'green'}}>{props.ile_aktywne}</p><p>Niedostępne: </p><p style={{color:'red'}}>{props.ile_nieaktywne}</p>
```

[image]

I want it to format as two lines

1. "Dostępne: 1"
2. "Niedostępne: 2"

Comment: Do you have to use `<p>` for this? I mean, if you can change the structure, why not use `<span>` for the values and move them inside the `<p>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a paragraph if you don't want to use it. That's what a `<span>` or `<div>` is for.

However, you can modify your HTML here:

```html
<p>Dostępne: <span style="color:green">1</span></p>
<p>Niedostępne: <span style="color:red">1</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

P tag will(If blocked behavior is not changed by CSS or Javascript) always creates a new line because it is a block tag. To get your output you can wrap it with a span tag as it is an inline tag.

```
<p>Dostępne: <span style={{color:'green'}}>{props.ile_aktywne}</span></p>
<p>Niedostępne: <span style={{color:'red'}}>{props.ile_nieaktywne}</span></p>
```

and if you want it as an ordered list add autonumbering. You can wrap with ol and replace p tag with li.

```
<ol>
  <li>Dostępne: <span style={{color:'green'}}>{props.ile_aktywne}</span></li>
  <li>Niedostępne: <span style={{color:'red'}}>{props.ile_nieaktywne}</span></li>
</ol>
```

Please check this as reference https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp